# How to put many parameters in a route in FOSJsRoutingBundle?

Tags: ajax, symfony, routes

I have a route with many parameters; but when I generate it with FOSJsRoutingBundle the navigator takes just the first parameter and generate a 404 Error

**Example:**

```
var id = $(this).val();
var name = "aaa";
$.ajax({
    url: Routing.generate('my_route', {
            'id': id,
            'name': name
         }),
  // rest of code
```

This syntax is it correct ?

**EDIT 1 :**

My route

```
my_route:
path:  /homepage/{id}/{name}
defaults: { _controller: AcmeBundle:Personal:changename}
options:
    expose: true
```

Comment: can you post the definition of the route  named `my_route`?

Comment: you can see it in the EDIT 1

Comment: Very strange, try without the `'` symbol like `Routing.generate('my_route', {
            id: id,
            name: name
         }`

Comment: i have tried it but no result :(

Comment: Can you post the segnature of the merhod changename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just incase someone else comes across this (I just wasted several hours)... If the parameter you are passing in matches the default, Routing.generate doesn't include the parameter.

For example:
Controller:

```
/**
* @Route("/plc/data/{systemID}/{tagID}", name="web_plc_data", options = { "expose" = true })
*/
public function indexAction(Request $request, $systemID=1, $tagID=16)
{
}
```

From twig:

```
var url = Routing.generate('web_data', { systemID: 10, tagID: 16 });
```

Will generate route:
/plc/data/10  (note 'tagID' parameter is ignored)

From twig:

```
var url = Routing.generate('web_data', { systemID: 10, tagID: 17 });
```

Will generate route:
/plc/data/10/17  (tagID parameter now included as it doesn't match default)

Best solution I could find was to set default parameters to NULL in the route, then initialise in the function itself (if null, set to some value).

Ie:

```
/**
* @Route("/plc/data/{systemID}/{tagID}", name="web_plc_data", options = { "expose" = true })
*/
public function indexAction(Request $request, $systemID=null, $tagID=null)
{
    if ($systemID==NULL)
    {      
        $systemID = 1;   
    }
    if ($tagID==NULL)
    {
        $tagID = 16;
    }
}
```

Implementation makes sense, just a bit confusing as it causes unexpected behavour.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why the navigator doesn't take the second parameter but i have solved the problem like this :

```
var id = $(this).val();
var name = "aaa";
var url  = Routing.generate('my_route', {
        id: id,
     }) + "/" + name;
$.ajax({
    url: url,
   // rest of code
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone else is dealing with the same issue, I just added the option expose true to the route since i'm using FOSJsRoutingBundle to generate the route in javascript, and everything work fine.

Here is the route definition:

```
/**
 * @Route("/show/{id}/{toValidate}", name="contribution_show", methods={"GET"}, options={"expose"=true})
 */
public function show(Contribution $contribution, $toValidate): Response
```

And here is my ajax call to generate the route:

url : Routing.generate('contribution_show', {id: id, toValidate: toValidate }),